# Parallelism takes much more time than a regular foreach

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

i wanted to improve my caesar cypher by adding parallelism capabilities but further measurement of code has demonstrated that the parallelism approach takes more time to finish than the normal approach.

why?

normal

```
public string CaesarEncrypt(string text, int positions, char[] charSet = null) {

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(charSet)) {
        charSet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789").ToCharArray();
    }

    List<char> charList = charSet.ToList();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder { Capacity = text.Length };

    foreach (char c in text) {
        int charPos = charList.IndexOf(c);

        if ((charPos == -1)) {
            sb.Append(c);
        } else {
            while (!(((charPos + positions) < (charSet.Length)))) {
                charPos -= charSet.Length;
            }
            sb.Append(charSet(charPos + positions));
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

parallel

```
public string CaesarEncrypt(string text, int positions, char[] charSet = null) {

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(charSet)) {
        charSet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789").ToCharArray();
    }

    List<char> charList = charSet.ToList();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder { Capacity = text.Length };

    Parallel.ForEach(text.ToArray(), (char c) =>
    {
        int charPos = charList.IndexOf(c);

        if ((charPos == -1)) {
            sb.Append(c);

        } else {
            while (!(((charPos + positions) < (charSet.Length)))) {
                charPos -= charSet.Length;
            }
            sb.Append(charSet(charPos + positions));

        }
    });
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be careful with this. The characters in the string returned may not be in the correct order. For example, one thread that was started after another may return first. As for performance, how many cores is your cpu? It doesn't seem like your method would take long to run, so the delegate setup may actually take longer than just running it on a single thread.

Comment: Only the public static members of StringBuilder are guaranteed to be threadsafe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_9  The append method almost certainly isn't and even if it is, you shouldn't rely on it being so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The management of the multi-threading has some cost. If the task in the body of the cycle is too tiny, this overhead can be larger than the gain of the multi-threading.

The other problem here that you append a `StringBuilder` inside if the parallel body. Since it is not guaranteed in which order the threads will finish, you might get a chaotic result at the end.

Comment: then this task cant be improved using parallelism? i dont understand then how multi-processor bruteforce algorithms works when they 'append' the chars in order, by executing the work in multiple threads

Comment: @Meska I would recommend expressing your problem in the form `text.ToArray().AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select(...)` to map to the final chars without changing their order.  It might be that you don't see performance gains until the processing task is much larger though, this doesn't look too intensive.